# email raw content decode

Tags: email, zend-framework, zend-mail

I have an not multipart email with this message:

```
Ciao come stai? Tutto bene? Io sono=
sempre qui, tutto ok. Come stanno i tuo=
i genitori?=
Hai visto le attivit=E0???
```

how I can decode raw content?
I'm using Zend Mail (1.12)

I see many answer, but none helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's encoded with `quoted-printable`.

check headers, and if message is encoded with `quoted-printable` use `Zend_Mime_Decode::decodeQuotedPrintable` function for decoding the message.